# Convert line comand curl to PHP curl from New Relic API

Tags: php, rest, curl, newrelic

i would like to have some help how to convert a comand line request via curl to the PHP curl. I´m trying to consume the New Relic REST service.

The sample code is like this:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:100' -i
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use curl_setopt_array() instead of curl command line flags.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications.json', //URL to the API
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true, // Instead of the "-i" flag
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('X-Api-Key:100') //Your New Relic API key
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl); 
print_r($resp);
```